# Python Pandas Boolean Dataframe Where Dataframe Equals False - Returns 0 instead of False?

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, where-clause, dataframe

If I have a `Dataframe` with `True`/`False` values only like this:

```
df_mask = pd.DataFrame({'AAA': [True] * 4,
                        'BBB': [False]*4,
                        'CCC': [True, False, True, False]}); print(df_mask)

    AAA    BBB    CCC
0  True  False   True
1  True  False  False
2  True  False   True
3  True  False  False
```

Then try to print where the values in the `dataframe` is equivalent to `False` like so:

```
print(df_mask[df_mask == False])
print(df_mask.where(df_mask == False))
```

My question is about column `CCC`.  Column `BBB` shows `False` (as I expect) but why is `index` `1` and `3` in column `CCC` equal to `0` instead of `False`?

```
   AAA    BBB  CCC
0  NaN  False  NaN
1  NaN  False    0
2  NaN  False  NaN
3  NaN  False    0
   AAA    BBB  CCC
0  NaN  False  NaN
1  NaN  False    0
2  NaN  False  NaN
3  NaN  False    0
```

Why doesn't it return a `dataframe` that looks like this?

```
   AAA    BBB   CCC
0  NaN  False   NaN
1  NaN  False False
2  NaN  False   NaN
3  NaN  False False
```

Comment: This looks like a bug to me, can you post this as an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues), thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure why, but if you're looking for a quick fix to convert it back to bools you can do the following:

```
>>> df_bool = df_mask.where(df_mask == False).astype(bool)
>>> df_bool
    AAA    BBB    CCC
0  True  False   True
1  True  False  False
2  True  False   True
3  True  False  False
```

This is because the returned dataframe has a different dtype: it's not longer a dataframe of bools.

```
>>> df2 = df_mask.where(df_mask == False)
>>> df2.dtypes
AAA    float64
BBB       bool
CCC    float64
dtype: object
```

This even occurs if you force it to a bool dtype from the getgo:

```
>>> df_mask = pd.DataFrame({'AAA': [True] * 4,
...                         'BBB': [False]*4,
...                         'CCC': [True, False, True, False]}, dtype=bool); print(df_mask)
    AAA    BBB    CCC
0  True  False   True
1  True  False  False
2  True  False   True
3  True  False  False
>>> df2 = df_mask.where(df_mask == False)
>>> df2
   AAA    BBB  CCC
0  NaN  False  NaN
1  NaN  False    0
2  NaN  False  NaN
3  NaN  False    0
```

If you're explicitly worried about memory, you can also just return a reference, but unless you're explicitly ignoring the old reference (in which case it shouldn't matter), be careful:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html

Comment: I'll also add that the try_cast and the inplace keyword arguments do nothing, suggesting that it's legitimately guessing the type is a float.